# MP3 + JPG into SWF?

Tags: windows, mp3, jpeg, swf

I'd like to compile an MP3 file and a JPG file into a single Flash SWF file that I can just upload and people don't need an MP3 plug-in to listen to it through a web browser.

Does someone know of a free Windows app that can easily do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your goal, why not find a flash audio player? If you control the page, you can implement the one below into your site. If it's a wordpress site, even better! Here are some leads.

This is a standalone version.
http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone

This page has examples.
http://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/

Comment: Right, but I wanted to check if there were an easier solution than Flash player in SWF + HTML + XML list + MP3 file.